# Basic import problem for qiskit_experiments module, how to fix?

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography

I'm trying to make use of the qiskit_experiments module but I always get a "No module named 'qiskit_experiments'" error while trying to import it. I've uninstalled and reinstalled qiskit in my environment but nothing changed. Also, I've tried installing it with both pip and pip3 but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to explicitly install the qiskit_experiments package:

```
pip install qiskit-experiments
```

Once this is done, you should be able to import it:

```
import qiskit_experiments
```